# Which superheroes went to Agartha (or Attilan)?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics

As I remember it, some superhero comic featured the mythical city of [Agartha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agartha).

I think, in this version, it was a city tucked away in some mountains, maybe under some sort of shield or dome?

I can't remember whether the heroes had a base there of if they were trying to protect it.

I've been trying to find it, but I can't even remember which comic it was... I think it was a Marvel comic. I read in in Sweden in the eighties, and it was probably in Swedish, so probably X-Men or Fantastic Four. I believe it was a team of heroes (perhaps the X-Men), not a single protagonist like Spiderman.

I have tried to search for it but I can't it, so I'm starting to think I remember it wrong, maybe it wasn't Agartha at all, but some other legendary city.

Can anybody help me find what comic it was, and maybe point to specific stories?

Edit: I updated the topic, hoping this might help anybody else who confuses Agartha with Attilan. Of course, it might just a be me.

Comment: I should add that this was probably published in the seventies or eighties.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add any details you remember - there is some guidance [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question). Also, could you include some paragraph breaks?

Comment: Can you add some info about which heros? Costume colours? Powers?

Comment: Could it be Attilan, the Inhuman city?

Comment: The problem with what you remember is that the main feature of Agartha is to be located in the centre of the earth, so if you remember it over the mountain probably you are thinking of another city. Your best bet are Shamballa, Shangri-la, and finally, if it was under a dome as you said, I agree with @eshier that you are probably thinking about Attilan, which during the '80 was "tucked away" in the mountains and fully covered by a dome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be thinking of Attilan, home of the Inhumans.

First introduced in *FANTASTIC FOUR* in the 1960s (around issues 44-47), the Inhumans were a race who could use something called terrigen mists to give themselves powers. They lived in Attilan (also called the Great Refuge), a city in the Himalayas. The city was trapped in a dome (placed there to protect it, but basically impenetrable). A couple of Inhumans were able to get out due to the powers of their pet dog (about the size of a small hippopotamus), Lockjaw, who could teleport. The Fantastic Four journey to Attilan. The dome was destroyed by Black Bolt, ruler of the Inhumans, who counts among his powers the ability to destroy things with his voice.

Comment: Yes I think that's it! Thanks, and kudos to @eshier who suggested Attilan.

Comment: Yes - I might have hesitated to add this if I hadn't realized the answer before reading the comments. My apologies, @eshier.

Comment: @RDFozz No worries.  I wasn't sure, so I asked.  I'm not that concerned about the reputation.  I would have had to look up the background anyway.